# How to stop links in rails app being prefixed with domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, content-tag

Both of these:

```
<%= content_tag("a", @a_model_instance.name, :href => @a_model_instance.url) %>
<a href="<%= @a_model_instance.url %>"><%= @a_model_instance.url %></a>
```

result in urls with href values of:

```
0.0.0.0:3000/model_name/www.the_url_i_want.com
```

How do you prevent this to get `a` tags with `href` values of `www.the_url_i_want.com`?
`@a_model_instance.url`returns the string `www.the_url_i_want.com`.

**edit - one solution**

This works:

```
<%= content_tag("a", @a_model_instance.name, :href => "http://#{@a_model_instance.url}") %>
<a href="http://<%= @a_model_instance.url %>"><%= @a_model_instance.url %></a>
```

But seems very non-railsy

Comment: if you add http at the beginning of the url it shouldnt prepend the domain I think

Comment: Thanks @ryudice, is there a "rails way" of doing this?  And do you want to post my answer as an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Comment: You should be using link_to not content_tag

Comment: well if you see the rails doc you will see it's the suggested way to do it http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html

Comment: be mindful or development vs productions urls, you don't want to be testing in development only to realize you hardcoded a production link.

Comment: If I know a certain field will always contain an external link I tend to use a before_save callback or something on the model to prepend http:// to the field if it was missing. Without the initial http:// link_to can't tell if you're giving it a relative path or a full external link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you add http at the beginning of the url it shouldnt prepend the domain I think

Answer (score 2):

You can prepend url with protocol if it's absent:

```
module UrlHelper
  def url_with_protocol(url)
    /^http/.match(url) ? url : "http://#{url}"
  end
end
```

And then:

```
link_to @a_model_instance.name, url_with_protocol(@a_model_instance.url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the url raw

```
 <%= link_to "Visit Stackoverflow", "http://www.stackoverflow.com/" %>
```

or try

```
<%= link_to "My url string", "#{@a_model_instance.url}" %>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion of `<%= link_to "My url string", "#{@a_model_instance.url}" %>` but that yields the same incorrect:  `0.0.0.0:3000/model_name/www.the_url_i_want.com`

Comment: is the url you are trying to render saved in the database?